# Understanding why certain clauses disallow deriving an empty clause and the relationship with satisfiability

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-explanation, boolean-algebra, satisfiability

If I had these clauses: {x,y,z},{¬x,¬y,¬z},{x,¬y},{¬x,z}. Why is it not possible to derive the empty clause from these by a resolution proof?

Also, is there a relationship between resolution proof and satisfiability? That is, if I find the clauses are satisfiable, does that cancel out automatically anything about having to use a resolution proof?

Comment: Yes there is. When the resolution procedure gives the empty clause, this means that the original set of clauses is *unsatisfiable*.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza I have asked a question on a similar topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4564279/2sat-problem-is-it-okay-to-derive-the-empty-clause-in-this-manner